# Pass .crt and .key files inside axios post request

Tags: node.js, ssl, axios

I want to pass a .crt and .key files in order to authenticate and  send Post Request using axios . I tired this :

```
 const fs = require('fs')
axios({
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
  method: 'post',
  url: myURL,
  cert:  fs.readFileSync("../src/certif/mycrt.crt"),
  key:  fs.readFileSync("../src/certif/mykey.key"),
  data: json_object
})
```

it failed to authenticate i get `AuthenticationFailed` error.

Comment: Try - `fs.readFileSync("../src/certif/mycrt.crt", { encoding: 'utf8' }) `

Answer (score 0):

file are binary data and for that you have to use form data. You can not use json to send files

Comment: I did send data as json. My problem is the cert and key field